# How can i make the Matrix of strings MxN using Scanner in Java?

Tags: java

I want to make a matrix which has M rows and N columns using the scanner.
If i try to do it this way:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int m=input.nextInt();
int n=input.nextInt();
String[][] matrix = new String[m][n];
for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
   matrix [i][j] = input.nextLine();
  }
}
```

It won't work.

How can i make this work?
Simple example of a matrix i want:

```
3 4
* * * *
* * * *
* * * *
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: It doesn't i am pretty new to Java, i need a simpler answer.

Comment: You need to explain the problem your facing by providing more details.

Comment: I assume there is enough detail in the code i have given which won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this code line: `input.nextLine();` directly under your `int n=input.nextInt();` line of code so as to consume the newline character still contained within the Scanner buffer when the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key was hit from the last `.nextInt()` method otherwise the following `.nextLine()` method will consume it and take it as input giving the effect that is was skipped over.

For example:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int m = input.nextInt();
int n = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
String[][] matrix = new String[m][n];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = input.nextLine();
    }
}
    
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrix[i]));
}
```

Comment: One thing, it doesn't recognize Arrays.ToString for some reason?